# how to save bytes to an NSString with UTF8 encoding

Tags: ios, nsstring, byte

I have some NSData that I am passing in as bytes

```
const void *bytes = [responseData bytes];
```

Those bytes were originally UTF8 formatted, I am now trying to get them into a UTF8 NSString without messing with the encoding at all.

I have previously written this if that copies the bytes into a cstring which normally would be fine unless I have any non english characters in the bytes which take two byte instead of one. This means any international characters in my string get messed up when I copy them into a cstring.

Hence the reason for needing to copying the bytes directly into a UTF8 formatted object.. preferably a NSString.. if possible.

This is how I was handling the conversion which I later found out is wrong but will hopefully give you a good idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```
else if (typeWithLocalOrdering == METHOD_RESPONSE)
        {
            cstring = (char *) malloc(sizeWithLocalOrdering + 1);
            strncpy(cstring, bytes, sizeWithLocalOrdering);
            cstring[sizeWithLocalOrdering] = '\0';

            NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
            methodResponseData =[resultString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]; // methodResponseData is used later on in my parsing method

            // Take care of the memory allocatoin, so that you can find the endoffile notification
            free(cstring);
            bytes += sizeWithLocalOrdering;
            length -= sizeWithLocalOrdering;

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with using `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cstring]`?

Comment: I dont want it going into the cstring at all.. I would like to avoid cstring because its messing up my previous encoding which is UTF8 all english characters are 1 byte but if I have a international character which I do its 2 bytes... which is 2 characters of a cstring which messes things up.. so I have to avoid cstring.

Comment: Of course, if your intent is to create the NSData object, why not just feed your cstring directly into an NSData creation?

Comment: You're not making sense.  You start with "bytes".  Why you copy that to "cstring", I don't know, but I was assuming you have your reasons.  You could use "bytes" directly.

Comment: how would I feed my bytes into a NSData object and account for sizing etc.. because i only want a portion of the total number of bytes.

Comment: How about `initWithBytes:length:encoding:`?

Comment: hrmm.. that might just work.. I'm going to try it and will let you know how I get on.

Comment: To create the NSData directly you'd use `dataWithBytes:length:`.

Comment: yup I have done that, but cannot find the 'initWithBytes:length:encoding:'

Comment: I have done this **NSData *tempData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeWithLocalOrdering];
            NSString *tempstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tempData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            methodResponseData =[tempstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]; // methodResponseData is used later on in my parsing method**

Comment: Why are you creating methodResponseData through that roundabout method rather than just using the original "bytes" value directly??

Comment: (`initWithBytes:length:encoding:` is for NSString.)

Comment: @Hot Licks I am doing that because I have to get it to NSUTF16 encoding from the original UTF8 encoding when it comes to me....

Comment: You do know how to find the references for [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSData), right?

Comment: You know, you could simply ask "How do I convert UTF8 to UTF16?"

Comment: That wasn't the initial problem that I had identified.... I actually didnt even think i was doing anything wrong untill you just highlighted it.. lol checking now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this: "This means any international characters in my string get messed up when I copy them into a cstring."  If "sizeWithLocalOrdering" is correct for the *actual* length of the byte string, it seems like your original code should work (though I would have used memcpy rather than strncpy).  If not, nothing's going to work.

**Update:**  OK, I see it.  Your original code was wrong here:

```
[NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

That should have been NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had a few interesting things happening that I was not expecting..

This is the code I used to get around working with the cstring and just take the bytes straight to a NSString as its original encoding then

```
NSString *tempstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeWithLocalOrdering encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            methodResponseData =[tempstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]; // methodResponseData is used later on in my parsing method
```